# Spring-@ControllerAdvice usage

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have requirement to upload image. Here 2 things are involved:
1.push the image to image server
2.save the image data to DB

This image push logic is common and have references in all controllers. I just want to maintain this image push logic in a interceptor or with a separate controller with @ControllerAdvice.

Request before delegating to the relevant controller handle the push logic annotated with @ControllerAdvice class and then pass the resultant data to relevant controller.

Any help can be appreciated on this.

Comment: What exactly is the "image push logic"? Receiving an image is as simple as defining a parameter for the controller method.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Interceptor is what you are looking for..

Look on this example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="myapp.server.controller") 
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new ImageUploadInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Now we define the interceptor:

```
@Component
public class ImageUploadInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        //Upload image here

        return true;
    }
}
```

Does this supply your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Right now my code is like below

```
@Controller
public class StoreController{

@Autowired services..

@RequestMapping("/store/image")

public ModelAndView saveStoreImage(@ModelAttribute("imageUpload") final ImageUpload,BindingResult){
```

// now first push the push image to content server
calling .sh file by using ProcessBuilder..it will return status code 0(0 indicates successfully image uploaded to static image server)

// now create real Image obj

```
final Image image = new Image(); // Image is my own domain
image.setEntityId(storeId);
image.setImageUri("/images/testImage.png");
imageService.save(image);
```

//this image uri is the image path with name  which we pushed before

//now make a service to save image into DB

```
}

}
```

same above code repeating in all controllers

@Controller
    public class Couponcontroller {

```
@Autowired Services....


@ReqMapping("/coupon/image")



  public ModelAndView saveCouponImage((@ModelAttribute("imageUplod") final ImageUpload,BindingResult){


 // same push logic like above executing sh file..is common always
//and then create Image and populate data save into DB

  }
    }
```

Now I want to maintain the common image upload(push) logic to a class with @ControllerAdvice and pass the image data to relevant controller.

Thanks,
Syamala.